# Flutter Flame audio: different volume of sound effects on different devices

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flame

I use Flame Audio to play sound effects in the game. I am faced with the problem that different effects sound at different volume relative to each other on different Android devices. Although on some devices and on the emulator, everything is fine. Please tell me how to approach the solution to this problem.

- flutter: 2.2.3
- flame: 1.0.0-releasecandidate.13
- flame_audio: 1.0.0-rc.1

Answer (score 3):

Sound playing can be very tricky, the reason you can see different results in different devices is because of the codecs available on the devices, which are not the same across different manufacturers and even different models from the same brand. I imagine that this is why you are seeing this issue.

The way to fix this, is probably to convert all the files to use the same format/codec (audacity is a good software that you can use). If you want to be even more safe, uncompressed formats (like wav) can be used, since they don't have compression, they are less prone to issues like these. But be aware that this will potentially increase the size of the files.

I hope that this helped.